# why does "top: -50%;" not work on this situation but "left: -50%" does

Tags: html, css

Here is my example code:

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}

.container .box{
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    left: -50%;
    top: -50%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

In the `.container` element, I set nothing on both width and height. But this example works on horizontal side, but not work on vertical side. In fact, the computed value of `top` is `-100px`, but the browser does not move the `.box` element `100px` to the top.

Comment: Create a similar demo in **Snippet** or **[JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)**.

Comment: Because the height of the container is 0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why does height and top attribute not work when position is relative?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774320/why-does-height-and-top-attribute-not-work-when-position-is-relative)

Comment: @Juhana chrome devtools shows that the height of the container is 200px.

Comment: The *computed* height is 200px...which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

`margin-top: -50%;` will do the trick.

Comment: no. if `margin-top` specified as percentage, it will be calculated with respect to the width of containing box. So when I set the `width: 400px` and `height: 100px`, the computed value of `top: -50%` is `-50px`, while the `margin-top: -50%` is `-200px` .

Comment: thats right, in such case you have to define **margin-top: -50px;**

Comment: suppose if the box is defined **height: 200px;** the the margin-top will be **-100px;**

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in webkit. If you search their bug tracker you'll see it shows up there from time to time ([14762](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14762), [23570](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23570)).

They even has a test case for this issue which surprisingly fails. You can try it here: https://bug-14762-attachments.webkit.org/attachment.cgi?id=15679

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late but here is the replacement of `top: -50%` to `transform: translateY(-50%);`